# where is the documentation for sencha calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, calendar

[Sencha Ext JS Calendar](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/calendar/index.html) looks suitable for my application, but could not able to find out whether it has a proper documentation or not ? My application is about showing and managing events through a calendar with several gadgets. Any recommendation ?

I am also considering to use [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know Sencha but Fullcalendar is largely documented and fully customizable. So my advise is to go for Fullcalendar.

Comment: hi, thank you so much for the reply! I am going with full calendar only as it has the MIT license.

Answer (score 2):

Hello    **Ext JS Calendar**  is nothing but an example application like **kitchensink** for ext js.  i dont think there will be documentation for those example applications.. but if you are keen to know how the application is done, please use inspect element of google Chrome or similar functionality in other browsers, and you will be able to find how it is done using Ext js ... it is simple

Answer (score 1):

I dont recommend FullCalendar to you if you want to manage your events.
That plugin lack manage functionality :(